# What's the bottle neck of server hit 100K request?

Tags: performance-tuning

The following are two graph of my digital ocean vps instance handle load test request. 10K/s, The only different is the request file size, first is 10K, the second is 20K. Can any one point out the bottle neck of my server setup?

P.S resources peak usage: CPU 20%, memory 10% **Network IO 69MB/s**(This may the problem lies) Disk IO 0.13%
[image]

[image]

### [image]

DigitalOcean 8-core instance 16G RAM, using Nginx serving static 10k/20k image file.

---

update! I put load balancer(HAProxy) into a separate VPS(8 core), I found the cpu usage is pretty high as the 3rd gram shows(5k request on 10k image)

Comment: The second graph shows 100.000 clients, not the 10K you mention. Also without knowing anything about your platform (is this a webserver, an MQ broker,...), the currently implemented configuration, the type of data being served (static vs. dynamic), amount of RAM, etc, it is difficult to diagnose anything.

Comment: @dawud thanks for your comment. I've updated the detail

Comment: How are you caching this static content?

Comment: What uplink? 690Mb/s looks like a good number for a 1gigbit port.

Comment: @dawud I'm using varnish before nginx as file server

Comment: @TomTom Do you think It exceeds the network limitation? What's the best solution for this situation? How about DNS load balancing

Comment: On the second graph there is an obvious drop in perfomance at 75k clients. How many worker processes did you configure on nginx? If the CPU peaked at 20% there is probably some room for more workers ( ie: with 8 cores you could go up to 8 workers )

Comment: @OlivierS I did make workers equal cores. I found an thing that if I  make the response file size in half(image file 20k -> 10k). The response time can drop dramatically(from 2000ms -> 100ms). Do you think the bottle neck is in the network bandwidth of Digital Ocean VPS service?

Comment: why don't you show up a graph with bandwith usage? If response time increases and bw stays flat, yes, it's a hint that you've reached the limit.

Comment: @OlivierS Can you recommend a app can track bandwidth usage? And I updated question with 3rd graph, I'm just  separate the load balancer(nginx or HAproxy) to another instance in the save private network(latency around 1ms). I found the CPU load of the load balancer is pretty hight hit 80% in 3K request/s almost 100% above 5K request/s

Comment: if the problem is uplink speed you should configure the load balancer with DSR, i do not know if haproxy can do this. You will have to alter your network configuration and make sure your vms are on the same vlan. For the bandwith isn't there a "bandwith" tab in your graphs? Else you can try dstat, it will not consume ressources.